# Mysql master-slave replication makes no sence

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave-replication

I have the following values in my.cnf settings in a simple Master -> Slave setup:

```
# MASTER my.cnf:
server-id = 1
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_format=ROW
binlog_do_db = db2
max_binlog_cache_size = 2G
binlog_cache_size = 32K
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size = 2G
binlog_stmt_cache_size = 32K
max_binlog_size = 100M
expire_logs_days=3

# SLAVE my.cnf
server-id = 2
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
relay-log = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log
binlog_format=ROW
replicate-wild-do-table=db2.%
max_binlog_cache_size = 2G
binlog_cache_size = 32K
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size = 2G
binlog_stmt_cache_size = 32K
max_binlog_size = 100M
expire_logs_days=3
```

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db) states that in row-based replication the USE database is ignored and only the changed database is taken under consideration. However I've noticed the following behavior:

```
USE db1;
CREATE TABLE db2.Fake (field1 int,field2 int);
```

This is not replicated to Slave.

When I change the USE to db2 the replication works.
Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Am I missing something here ?
```

sure, just few row above:

> For example, DDL statements such as CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE are always logged as statements, without regard to the logging format in effect, so the following statement-based rules for --binlog-do-db always apply in determining whether or not the statement is logged.